# Spring Data Redis Lettuce Connection Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, lettuce, redis-sentinel

I have spring boot application with MYSQL DB and i am caching the data in Redis in server layer with @Cacheable Annotation

```
@Cacheable(value= "employeeCache", key= "#customerId")
@Override
public Customer getEmployee(String customerId) {
    Optional<Customer> cust = customerRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(customerId));
    if(cust.isPresent()) {
        return cust.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am using 1 Master 2 Slave and 2 sentinel node, i have deployed the application in docker containers, in AWS ec2 ubuntu instance.

Application and Redis Master/Slave Set up works fine.

When Redis master container goes down, one of the slave becomes master, that also works fine

But once one of the slave becomes master, then Spring boot not able to connect to Redis, i am getting connection time out, it only work if i restart the container.

Please check if any mistake in the configuration.

**Java Logs**

```
2020-05-21 18:04:50.016 ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Redis command timed out; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute(s)] with root cause

io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute(s)
        at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createTimeoutException(ExceptionFactory.java:51) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.0.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandExpiryWriter.lambda$potentiallyExpire$0(CommandExpiryWriter.java:167) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.0.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar!/:4.1.49.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

**Spring Boot Files**

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/customerdb
    username: root
    password: root

  jpa:
    show-sql: true

    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


  cache:
    type: redis  

  redis:
    sentinel:
      master: mymaster
      nodes:
        - redis-sentinel:26379
        - redis-sentinel-1:26380

management:
  endpoints:
    web: 
      exposure:
        include:
        - "*"
server:
  port: 8080

logging:
  file:
    name: customer.log
    path: ../logs
```

**Files for Redis and Spring Boot deployment**

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  redis-master:
    container_name: redis-master
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis-master:/data"
    networks:
      - backend

  redis-slave:
    container_name: redis-slave
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis-slave:/data"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
    networks:
      - backend

  redis-slave-1:
    container_name: redis-slave-1
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis-slave:/data"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
    networks:
      - backend    

  redis-sentinel:
    container_name: redis-sentinel
    ports:
      - "26379:26379"
    build: redis-sentinel
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
    networks:
      - backend

  redis-sentinel-1:
    container_name: redis-sentinel-1
    build: redis-sentinel
    ports:
      - "26380:26379"
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
    networks:
      - backend

  docker-mysql:
    restart: always
    container_name: docker-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: customerdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    volumes:
      - db-data-new:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - backend

  customer-app:
    container_name: java-sentinel
    restart: on-failure
    image: kuldeep99/customer-sentinel:v10
    expose:
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - /tmp:/logs
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
      - redis-sentinel
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  db-data-new:

networks:
  backend:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM redis

EXPOSE 26379
ENV SENTINEL_QUORUM 2
ENV SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER 3000
ENV SENTINEL_FAILOVER 3000
ADD sentinel.conf /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
RUN chown redis:redis /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
ADD sentinel-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sentinel-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sentinel-entrypoint.sh"]
```

sentinel-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i "s/\$SENTINEL_QUORUM/$SENTINEL_QUORUM/g" /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
sed -i "s/\$SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER/$SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER/g" /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
sed -i "s/\$SENTINEL_FAILOVER/$SENTINEL_FAILOVER/g" /etc/redis/sentinel.conf

redis-server /etc/redis/sentinel.conf --sentinel
```

sentinel.conf

```
port 26379
protected-mode no
dir /tmp
sentinel monitor mymaster redis-master 6379 $SENTINEL_QUORUM
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster $SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster $SENTINEL_FAILOVER
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -2):

I think you are not setting up the topology refresh config.
You can enable them like this -

**Solution 1**:

Upgrade to SpringBoot 2.3.0 or above. And add the following configuration items

```
spring.redis.timeout=60s
spring.redis.lettuce.cluster.refresh.period=60s
spring.redis.lettuce.cluster.refresh.adaptive=true
```

**Solution 2**:

Configure LettuceConnectionFactory and set topology refresh strategy.

```
@Bean
public DefaultClientResources lettuceClientResources() {
    
    
    return DefaultClientResources.create();
}

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties, ClientResources clientResources) {
    
    

    ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions topologyRefreshOptions = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
            .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(30)) //按照周期刷新拓扑
            .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers() //根据事件刷新拓扑
            .build();

    ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
            //redis命令超时时间,超时后才会使用新的拓扑信息重新建立连接
            .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .topologyRefreshOptions(topologyRefreshOptions)
            .build();

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .clientResources(clientResources)
            .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions)
            .build();

    RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration(redisProperties.getCluster().getNodes());
    clusterConfig.setMaxRedirects(redisProperties.getCluster().getMaxRedirects());
    clusterConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));

    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfig, clientConfiguration);

    return lettuceConnectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Not answering the question. The OP is using Redis Sentinel not Redis Cluster.